# mysqli - Using SELECT FOUND_ROWS() with prepared statements

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I was wondering how to include `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` to an existing query using `LIMIT`, or if there is a better way to get the total row count without `LIMIT`.

```
//SELECT * just for question

$q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
                                 FROM countries_ship c
                                 JOIN items i
                                ON c.item_id = i.id
                                JOIN item_expire e
                                ON c.item_id = e.item_id
                                JOIN users u
                                ON i.user_id = u.id
                                LEFT JOIN bids b
                                ON i.id = b.item_id
                                LEFT JOIN publishers p
                                ON i.item_publisher = p.id
                                LEFT JOIN tags_rel tr
                                ON c.item_id = tr.item_id
                                JOIN tags t
                                ON t.id = tr.tag_id
                                LEFT JOIN countries co
                                ON i.item_location = co.id
                                WHERE ".$where."
            GROUP BY i.id ORDER BY ".$order." ".$limit."");

    $count_rows = $this->db->mysqli->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");

/* return of var_dump($count_rows);
object(mysqli_result)#74 (5) {
  ["current_field"]=>
  int(0)
  ["field_count"]=>
  int(1)
  ["lengths"]=>
  NULL
  ["num_rows"]=>
  int(1)
  ["type"]=>
  int(0)
}
*/

$prep = join("", $prep);

    call_user_func_array('mysqli_stmt_bind_param', array_merge ( array($q, $prep), $this->helperClass->valRef($ref) ) );

    $q->execute();
    $rows = $this->helperClass->bindResults($q);

    $q->close();

    return $rows;
```

Not sure if this is 100% efficient but this is how I solved my problem.

1. Changed the beginning of the query `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`
2. Created new array - `$resArray = array()`
3. Moved the second query like suggested and added both results to `$resArray`.

   ```
           $q->execute();

           $rows = $this->helperClass->bindResults($q);

           $q->close();

           $count_rows = $this->db->mysqli->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");

           $count = mysqli_fetch_assoc($count_rows);

           $resArray[] = $count;
           $resArray[] = $rows;

           return $resArray;
   ```

Comment: select count(*) as total_item from ...

Comment: won't that just return the count with limit?

Comment: Like you do normally: Add `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` to your `SELECT` and issue a second query to get the results.

Comment: for count Please Dont use limit (if possible)

Comment: `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` is really good when running any sort of paginated result as you get the total number of responses back instantly... IMO it's much better than mucking about with `COUNT(*)`

Comment: That's what I need it for ... pagination

Comment: @jeroen I still don't understand. Show me what you mean please. I need to add it to $rows ...

Comment: I mean that it is no different from a non-prepared statement. Do it like you normally would do it and / or check the manual.

Comment: What @jeroen is saying is basically just change your `SELECT * ... ` to `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, {table.column etc} ... ` Once you've done that you can just run another query afterwards (`SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`) to get the total number of results which *would have been found* had there been no limit .... but he can answer it, he hit the nail on the head :)

Comment: @CD001 Thanks, but I think I'll pass, the query itself it pretty straight-forward but will lead to new problems as the function output will have to change, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track with the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, you will only need to move where you execute the query for counting the resutls. As it will only be valid after you run the original query.
So, move `$count_rows = $this->db->mysqli->query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()");` to after `$q->execute();`

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now'` after moving `$count_rows` after `$q->execute()`. So I moved it after `$rows = $this->helperClass` ... but the `var_dump` result is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

While I could be wrong, it seems that if you just want to get a count of rows that have matched your criteria, you should just use the counting aggregate function of SQL like this:

```
SELECT 
    i.id,
    count(*)
FROM 
    countries_ship c
        JOIN items i
            ON c.item_id = i.id
        JOIN item_expire e
            ON c.item_id = e.item_id
        JOIN users u
            ON i.user_id = u.id
        LEFT JOIN bids b
            ON i.id = b.item_id
        LEFT JOIN publishers p
            ON i.item_publisher = p.id
        LEFT JOIN tags_rel tr
            ON c.item_id = tr.item_id
        JOIN tags t
            ON t.id = tr.tag_id
        LEFT JOIN countries co
            ON i.item_location = co.id
WHERE 
    ".$where."
GROUP BY 
    i.id
```

On the other hand if you want to get a count AND all the details in a way you can paginate them, it might be better off to simply run two queries - one for the aggregate count and the other for the limited results.

Edit: I have left the i.id grouping in the query as it will then give you a count per i.id of the rows that match. If you just want the TOTAL count altogether, you can remove it from both the select clause as well as the group by, getting rid of the group by completely.

Comment: Yeah ... I need to get details, limit the rows to 12 and count all rows without the limit. And I also need to count the bids `COUNT(b.bids) as bids`. That's why I used `GROUP BY`